# Product price in emails

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Cart page is `woocommerce_cart` but I made a custom checkout page with contact form 7. All fields are displayed in email except carts total. Here is my checkout page using *contact form 7.* How am I able to display cart total amount or cart details in email after submit button?

```html
<ol>
    <li>Product Info [textarea* ProductInfo placeholder "What Do You Want to Buy? (Product Name)"]</li>
    <li>Product Quantity [number Quantity placeholder "Enter Product Quantity"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Name [text* Name placeholder "Enter Your Name"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Address [text* Address placeholder "Enter Your Address"]</li>
    <li>City [text* City placeholder "Enter Your City"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Zip Code [text* ZipCode placeholder "Enter Zip Code"]</li>
    <li>Country [text* Country placeholder "Enter Your Country"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Contact Number [tel* ContactNumber placeholder "Enter Your Contact Number"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>State [text* State placeholder "Enter State"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Email [email* Email placeholder "Enter a valid email address"]</li>
    <li>Shipping Address [textarea* ShippingAddress placeholder "Enter Your Shipping Address (Address, City, Zip Code, Country, State)"]</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>How You Gonna Pay Us [select* Pay multiple include_blank "Bitcoin" "Paypal" "Bank Transfer" "Cash App" "Zelle App"]</li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

and after that submit button is placed at the end.

Comment: How are you displaying the cart total in your check out form, it is not shown in your form.

Comment: thats the question, btw by using "product info request" only product name is dispalyed in emails...how to show product price?

Comment: well your question is cart total in your email...please update the question

Comment: updated........

Comment: So you want a singular product price, or all of the items from the cart?